# How can I make a block pass a parameter type of a certain class?

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-blocks

I've defined a block in one of my headers like so:

```
typedef MyViewClass* (^MyBlock)(UIViewController *viewController);
```

I need to use this block in several different cases, and I'm currently doing this:

```
object.block = ^MyViewClass *(UIViewController *viewController) {
    ...
    return something;
};
```

How can I define my block so when I use it, I can use any subclass of `UIViewController` directly in the parameter list? For example, `UITableViewController`. When I try now, I get a compiler warning. I guess I'm looking for something along the lines of `instancetype`, only for a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. It's no different than the parameter types of a method. You can't have a method in some base class that takes a `UIViewController` and then when implementing the method in some derived class, the method can't suddenly be `UITableViewController`.

A block definition is similar. It's defined one way and all implementations must honor that definition.

The best you can do is create a local variable in the specific block. Example:

```
object.block = ^MyViewClass *(UIViewController *viewController) {
    UITableViewController *tableViewController = (UITableViewController *)viewController;
    ...
    return something;
};
```

Of course this assumes you know that the block caller will really pass a `UITableViewController`.

Comment: This was my fear, I wanted to try and tuck the cast in the block definition. P.S; way I was thinking about it compared to a method was, the header can specify `UIViewController`, but in any implementation you can pass through subclasses of `UIViewController` without trouble.